# How do I find the pooled standard error of the mean in R?

Tags: r, standard-error, psych

I have the following result from doing some descriptive statistics on my data:

```
> psych::describeBy(mydata_young$length, mydata_young$Strain)

 Descriptive statistics by group 
group: Hubbard
   vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min   max range  skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 18 93.07 4.97   93.5   93.19 3.71 82.6 101.5  18.9 -0.33    -0.63 1.17
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
group: Ross
   vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min   max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 43 90.61 5.08     91   90.53 4.15 81.1 102.9  21.8 0.07    -0.41 0.77
```

How do I convert these two separate standard errors into one pooled standard error of the mean? Is there a command, or an easy way to do it by hand?

Comment: is there a reason that `describe(mydata_young$length)` wouldn't do it?  (You *can* use `n` and `se` to construct the pooled SE, but since you have the data ...)

Comment: I might just be stupid.. I'm sorry, I'm very bad at statistics. The thing is, I have multiple independent variables such as Strain, Enrichment, and a couple others, which may influence multiple dependent variables such as length, thickness, yield to name a few. So basically if I understand correctly, the pooled standard error for length will always be the same, even if the independent variables aren't? Thanks!